# how to convert characters like these,"a³ a¡ a´a§" in unicode, using python?

Tags: python, string, unicode, utf-8, urllib

i'm making a crawler to get text html inside, i'm using beautifulsoup.

when I open the url using urllib2, this library converts automatically the html that was using portuguese accents like " ã ó é õ " in another characters like these "a³ a¡ a´a§"

what I want is just get the words without accents

contrã¡rio -> contrario

I tried to use this algoritm, bu this one just works when the text uses words like these "olá coração contrário"

```
   def strip_accents(s):
      return ''.join((c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', s) if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn'))
```

Comment: Is your problem that the automatic conversion *isn't correct*, or that you want to reduce fully accented characters to their closest ASCII equivalent?  Or is it a little of both?

Comment: The normalization trick displayed in the question is a good way to remove accents. The only problem must be that the conversion doesn't work -- if the OP's rendering of the output is somewhat approximate, the problem could be that the data is UTF-8 but is being interpreted as latin-1.

Comment: I realized that for anothers web sites exactly what I'm doing solves. The problem is this web site.
Sounds strange to me, because when I see the source code of the web page seen's like the anothers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you have to ensure that your crawler returns HTML that is unicode text (Eg. Scrapy has a method response.body_as_unicode() that does exactly this)

Once you have unicode text that you cant make sense of, the step of going from unicode text to equivalent ascii text lies here - http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode/0.04.1

```
from unidecode import unidecode
print unidecode(u"\u5317\u4EB0")
```

The output is "Bei Jing"

Answer (score -2):

You have byte data.  You need Unicode data.  Isn’t the library supposed to decode it for you? It has to, because you don’t have the HTTP headers and so lack the encoding.

## EDIT

Bizarre though this sounds, it appears that Python does not   support content decoding in its web library. If you run this program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python    
import re
import urllib.request
import io
import sys

for s in ("stdin","stdout","stderr"):
    setattr(sys, s, io.TextIOWrapper(getattr(sys, s).detach(), encoding="utf8"))

print("Seeking r\xe9sum\xe9s")

response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://nytimes.com/')
content  = response.read()

match    = re.search(".*r\xe9sum\xe9.*", content, re.I | re.U)
if match:
    print("success: " + match.group(0))
else:
    print("failure")
```

You get the following result:

```
Seeking résumés
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ur.py", line 16, in <module>
    match    = re.search(".*r\xe9sum\xe9.*", content, re.I | re.U)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/re.py", line 158, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

That means `.read()` is returning raw bytes not a real string.  Maybe you can see something in the [doc for the `urllib.request` class](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/urllib.request.html) that I can’t see.  I can’t believe they actually expect you to root around in the `.info()` return and the `<meta>` tags and figure out the stupid encoding on your own and then decode it so you have a real string.  That would be utterly lame! I hope I’m wrong, but I spent a good time looking and couldn’t find anything useful here.

Compare how easy doing the equivalent is in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl    
use strict;
use warnings;    
use LWP::UserAgent;

binmode(STDOUT, "utf8");    
print("Seeking r\xe9sum\xe9s\n");

my $agent = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $response = $agent->get("http://nytimes.com/");

if ($response->is_success) {
    my $content = $response->decoded_content;
    if ($content =~ /.*r\xe9sum\xe9.*/i) {
        print("search success: $&\n");
    } else {
        print("search failure\n");
    } 
} else {
    print "request failed: ", $response->status_line, "\n";
}
```

Which when run dutifully produces:

```
Seeking résumés
search success: <li><a href="http://hiring.nytimes.monster.com/products/resumeproducts.aspx">Search Résumés</a></li>
```

Are you sure you have to do this in Python?  Check out how much richer and more user-friendly the Perl [`LWP::UserAgent`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP%3a%3aUserAgent) and [`HTTP::Response`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP%3a%3aResponse) classes are than the equivalent Python classes. Check it out and see what I mean.

Plus with Perl you get better Unicode support all around, such as full grapheme support, something which Python currently lacks.  Given that you were trying to strip out diacritics, this seems like it would be another plus.

```
 use Unicode::Normalize;
 ($unaccented = NFD($original)) =~ s/\pM//g;
```

Just a thought.

Comment: Have you tried using content.decode("utf-8") to convert content retrieved to a string before doing regular expression searches on it?  If you do this re.search(".*r\xe9sum\xe9.*", content.decode("utf-8"), re.I | re.U) it works fine

Comment: @James: But I shouldn’t have to do that. Never guess the encoding.  Notice you don’t specify which one to use with Perl’s `decode_content()` method, because it uses the HTTP headers to find the right mime type. I cannot understand why this is missing from Python, because you cannot use the library without it.

Comment: @wberry: I am perfectly aware of what I am doing: didn’t you read *“That means `.read()` is returning raw bytes not a real string.”* ??? The point is that there is no `decoded_content` method in the Python class that produces a properly decoded string the way there is in the Perl class.  **And there should be.** Making the user do it for himself is not  acceptable.

Comment: It would be "utterly lame" if HTTP was only supposed to be capable of delivering character data.  But HTTP can just as easily deliver byte-streams such as images, therefore the `urllib` API gives you bytes.  The Beautifulsoup package is intended to bridge that gap.  Please do not rush to judgement of technologies unless the question invites this.

Comment: @wberry I did not “rush to judgement”.  It is considered and studied professional opinion. And this is not an HTML thing: it is a byte string versus character string matter.  There are other encoded types that can come back. `text/plain` as charset CP1252 or MacRoman or whatever. Give them the raw bytes in a `content` method, but give them the decoded string in a `decoded_content` method. Python makes people work too hard for something that should be built into it: to wit, character strings. Never make the user handle raw bytes when they want characters.

Comment: @tchrist Whatever the differences between python and perl are and how much more convenient you think perl is is irrelevant.  This is a question about python not perl, and this type of discussion should be done elsewhere.

Comment: @tchrist If you look at my first comment you will see the answer.  I never said python was perfect nor did I say that the answer was wrong, you simply went on about how much more convenient it is in perl, which, in my opinion is not what is being asked for here.

Comment: @James: No, your first comment does not solve the problem, because it does not use the charset from the HTTP header.