# Python raw strings and html parsing

Tags: python

How do python raw strings and string literals work? I'm trying to make a webscraper to download pdfs from a site. When I search the string it works, but when I try to implement it in python I always get None as my answer

```
import urllib
import re    
url="" //insert url here
sock=urllib.urlopen(url)
htmlSource=sock.read();
sock.close();

m=re.match(r"<a href.*?pdf[^>]*?", raw(htmlSource))
print m



$ python temp.py
None
```

The raw function is from here: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65211-convert-a-string-into-a-raw-string/

That said, how can I complete this program so that I can print out all of the matches and then download the pdfs?

Thanks!

Comment: Any reason you're using a regex instead of [a real HTML parser](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)?

Comment: part of this is also just an exercise in regex for me

Comment: This question isn't really about "Python raw literals", is it?

Comment: Title shouold have been raw strings then, i guess. I'm not really sure, because if i replace "raw(htmlSource)" in my code with the actual source it works fine. But right now it returns None

Comment: You can do `'%r' % htmlSource` instead of `raw` to get a Python raw string.  Do you have a reason for parsing a raw string instead of the real string?

Comment: @Peter That's really not the same thing. First off, "a Python raw string" is nonsensical (see my answer for details); second, the normal spelling is `repr(htmlSource)`; third, that leaves quotes on either side of the string which is usually not what's desired when people think they want to do this (what they really want to do is **escape** the string); fourth, after removing the quotes you get something that is "parsed" by putting it within `""`, not within `r""`.

Comment: @Karl `('%r' % htmlSource)[1:-1]`, then.  I was just pointing out a far easier way to do what the linked Activestate code was trying to achieve.

Comment: Sure, but it's still a generally meaningless thing to do, and still corresponds to an "ordinary" string literal rather than a "raw" one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be very confused.

A 'string literal' is a string that you type into the program. Because there needs to be a clear beginning and end to your string, certain characters become inconvenient to have within the middle of the string, and escape sequences must be used to represent them.

Python offers 'raw' string literals which have different rules for how the escape sequences are interpreted: the same rules are used to figure out where the string ends (so a single backslash, followed by the opening quote character, doesn't terminate the string), but then the stuff between the backslashes doesn't get transformed. So, while `'\''` is a string that consists of a single quote character (the `\'` in the middle is an escape sequence that produces the quote), `r'\''` is a string that consists of a backslash and a quote character.

The raw string literal produces an object of type `str`. It is the same type as produced by an ordinary string literal. These are often used for the **pattern** for a regex operation, because the strings used for regexes often need to contain a lot of backslashes. If you wanted to write a regex that matched a backslash in the source text, and you didn't have raw string literals, then you would need to put, perhaps surprisingly, four backslashes between the quotes in your source code: the Python compiler would interpret this as a string containing two real backslashes, which in turn represents "match a backslash" in the regex syntax.

The function you found is an imperfect attempt to re-introduce escape sequences into input text. *This is not what what you want to do*, doesn't even really make sense, and doesn't meet the author's own spec anyway. It seems to be based on a misconception similar to your own. The concept of a "raw equivalent of" a string is nonsensical. There is, really, *no such thing as* "a raw string"; raw string **literals** are a convenience for creating ordinary strings.

You want to search for the pattern within `htmlSource`. It *is already in the form you need it to be in*. Your problem has *nothing to do with string escapes*. *When a string comes from user input, file input, or basically anything other than the program source, it is not processed the way string literals are, unless you explicitly arrange for that to happen.* If the web page contains a backslash followed by an n, the string that gets read by `urllib` contains, in the corresponding spot, exactly that - a backslash followed by an n, not a newline.

The problem is as follows: you want to **search** the string, as you said: "when I search the string it works". You are currently **matching** the string. See the documentation:

```
Help on function match in module re:

match(pattern, string, flags=0)
    Try to apply the pattern at the start of the string, returning
    a match object, or None if no match was found.
```

Your pattern does not appear at the beginning of the string, since the HTML for the webpage does not start with the `<a>` tag you are looking for.

You want `m=re.search(r"<a href.*?pdf[^>]*?", htmlSource)`.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237241/how-to-convert-characters-like-these-a-a-aa-in-unicode-using-python). It seems that Python’s `urllib` is a lot less user‐friendly — and Unicode‐friendly — than it should be. It seems to force you to deal with ugly raw bytes content instead of decoding it for you into a normal string.

Comment: OP's problem doesn't **seem** to involve unicode, although that certainly may cause further problems down the road. At least in 2.x, Python is happy to treat "ugly raw bytes content" as a string. That isn't nearly as bad as trying to parse HTML with a regex ;) and the OP's apparent confusion over "raw strings" is a much more important issue IMO. (`r''` is not an antonym to `u''`.)

Comment: @tchrist I thought you said "Unicorn-friendly", and got excited :/